# Better naming convention for Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

When naming a Jupyter notebook, if spaces are used, i.e.

```
This is my notebook.ipynb
```

then it renders very nicely when opened with the web browser. However, spaces are evil on the command line environment. But if instead:

```
This_is_my_notebook.ipynb
```

or

```
This-is-my-notebook.ipynb
```

then the title rendered does *not* look as good. Any suggestions for an alternative convention but still look somewhat nice?

Comment: [Jupyter Coding Style](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development_guide/coding_style.html) This link might be helpful. :)

Answer (score 9):

This is really going to depend on your personal preferences, and use cases. Here is the approach I use:

#### My Approach

```
[#]_[2-4 word description]_[DS-initials]_[ISO 8601 date].ipynb
```

e.g.

```
- jupyter-notebooks
  + 1_exploratory_analysis_ag_2019-02-16.ipynb
  + 1_exploratory_analysis_jw_2019-02-19.ipynb
  + 1_exploratory_analysis.ipynb
  + 1_exploratory_analysis.py
  + 1_exploratory_analysis.html
  + 2_topic_modeling_ag_2019-02-20.ipynb
  + 2_topic_modeling.ipynb
  + 2_topic_modeling.py
  + 2_topic_modeling.html
  + dev_2019-02-15.ipynb
  + dev_2019-02-18.ipynb
  + dev.ipynb
  + dev.py
  + dev.html
```

- Here I've got all the notebooks in a folder called `jupyter-notebooks`. Files and script outputs would generally live outside of this folder.
- If applicable, notebooks are numbered in a logical order e.g. date first created. In many cases it will not make sense to number the files (e.g. [this repo of mine](https://github.com/agalea91/crypto-monetary-base/tree/master/jupyter-notebooks)).
- Notebooks are versioned with timestamps and (optionally) initials of the most recent author. This can be done automatically with a post-save hook (see below).
- Non timestamped versions of the notebooks have `.py` and `.html` versions. By committing the `.py` files to git, you can get some benefits of version control. These files can also be generated with a post-save hook.
- Miscellaneous development work can be put in `dev...` files.

I have a post-save hooks set up to automate this. In my configuration file (`~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`) I've got:

```py
import os
from subprocess import check_call
import glob
import datetime
import re

def timestamped_file(fname):
    return bool(re.match('.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.ipynb', fname))

def post_save(model, os_path, contents_manager):
    if model['type'] != 'notebook':
        return # only do this for notebooks

    # Post-save hook for converting notebooks to .py scripts
    d, fname = os.path.split(os_path)
    if not timestamped_file(fname):
        check_call(['jupyter', 'nbconvert', '--to', 'script', fname], cwd=d)
        check_call(['jupyter', 'nbconvert', '--to', 'html', fname], cwd=d)

    # Post-save hook for saving datestamped versions of the notebook
    notebooks = glob.glob('*.ipynb') + glob.glob('jupyter-notebooks/*.ipynb')
    if notebooks:
        latest_mod_file = max(notebooks, key=os.path.getctime)
        # Don't do this for datestamped notebooks
        if not timestamped_file(latest_mod_file):
            date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            fname_timestamped = '{}_{}.ipynb'.format(os.path.splitext(latest_mod_file)[0], date)
            check_call(['cp', latest_mod_file, fname_timestamped])


c.FileContentsManager.post_save_hook = post_save
```

If saving a non-timestamped file, this will automatically convert to `.py` and `.html`, and make a timestamped version.

#### Another Approach

My convention was heavily inspired by [this blog post](https://www.svds.com/jupyter-notebook-best-practices-for-data-science/). They describe conventions that I began using a couple years ago before adopting my own variation.

Here's the example they include:

```
- develop
  + [ISO 8601 date]-[DS-initials]-[2-4 word description].ipynb
  + 2015-06-28-jw-initial-data-clean.html
  + 2015-06-28-jw-initial-data-clean.ipynb
  + 2015-06-28-jw-initial-data-clean.py
  + 2015-07-02-jw-coal-productivity-factors.html
  + 2015-07-02-jw-coal-productivity-factors.ipynb
  + 2015-07-02-jw-coal-productivity-factors.py
- deliver
  + Coal-mine-productivity.ipynb
  + Coal-mine-productivity.html
  + Coal-mine-productivity.py
```

As you can see, there are separate folders (and naming conventions) for the development and delivery notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself searching for this answer as well...

I scoured through some popular GitHub repositories involving .ipynb files, under the pretense of the work being reputably standardized. I found that there was no standard between utilizing dashes and underscores; however, I **didn't** see any notebooks using spaces - so don't do that.

Sources:

https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/tree/master/example-notebooks

https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/tree/master/Supporting_Notebooks